# Twilio simply will not answer the phone correctly

Tags: twilio-php

Okay, I am at basically the very beginning here. I have a bit of code that calls my phone and is supposed to say "Tim is testing the system" to me.

My code can make the call. I include a callback URL in it that I know it can get to. When I run the callback code, it outputs "
Tim is testing the system
" (Obviously without the quotes).

But when I make the call with Twilio is errors out and when I look at the debugger the problem seems to be that twilio does not see the body (I see "No Body" in the debugger output).

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? The code that is giving me the problems is this :

```
    include(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'libraries/Twilio/Twilio.php');
    include(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'libraries/Twilio/Twilio/Twiml.php');
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $sayMessage = 'Tim is testing the system';
    $response->say($sayMessage);
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo $response;
```

Comment: Can you share the TwiML which is returned by your Twiml url? Also can you please confirm if you are not using test credentials to make voice call? You can also check the voice call logs on Twilio portal under your account to see what could be the reason behind failure.

Comment: I am not using test credentials. And the XMl returned  is this (Replace the square brackets with the right ones since apparently stackoverflow removed my XML formatting) :

[Response][Say]Tim is testing the system[/Say][/response]

Comment: Also, to be very specific, the error is "12100 Document Parse Failure"

Comment: I updated my answer. You can try by returning hard coded TwiML (one line containig all the TwiML) just to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

TwiML looks good.

There can be multiple reasons.

The URL which is return TwiML should be available publicly for Twilio to access. Locally hosted URL or internal network URL will not work.

Making UrL public is a security risk but Twilio Offers way using which you can verify that the request to the URL is being made by Twilio only. If it's not twilio you can reject the request straight away.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/08/new-feature-http-auth-for-twilio.html

Voice Calls might not enabled for the country you are trying to call in you twilio account.
You need to loging to twilio portal and navigate to following URL. https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international

Here you can enable/disable countries for both SMS and Voice Call. Check if the country you are trying to make voice calls to is enabled in that page or not. If not you can enable it and try making Voice call again.

Also as I mentioned in my comment you can check the voice call logs by browsing to https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls after loggin into Twilio account. You can locate the failed voice call and selecting it would provide the details about the reason of the failure.

And in case of error 12100 Document Parse Failure, you need to make sure there are no extra spaces or newline characters in start and end of the TwiMl string and between the XML declaration and the root element.

Comment: I know it is not the country - it is my smart phone I am calling and it is a Jacksonville, FL number.

And I can certainly locate the problem in the debugger. It consistently shows that the body of the returned stuff as "No Body" which is obviously the problem with the parse error... But I am not sure why it is returning no body when I can see it returning formatted XML...

Comment: Let's put it this way - if I use a Twiml Bin I know that I can have the system say what i want it to. So it's not the way the call is being made, it is in the callback I have. For some reason Twilio is not seeing the twiml I am writing out in the code above... But I don't see why

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you have written to make voice call?

Comment: require_once(FCPATH . APPPATH . '/libraries/Twilio/Twilio.php');
        $this->load->library(array('Twilio_Outgoing', 'Twilio_Incoming'));
        $client = new Services_Twilio('XXX', 'XXX');
        try {
            $call = $this->twilio_outgoing->account->calls->create(
                '+XXX', // A Twilio number in your account
                '+XXX', // The visitor's phone number
                "XXX"
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
        //print_r($call);
        echo $call->sid;

Comment: I removed the stuff I can't share and made it "XXX"

Comment: And I know it can call since the system calls my phone every time - but I get the "We're sorry, an application error has ocurred" message

Comment: I looked at your code. I do not see the code where you are passing the URL of TwiML when you initiate voice call by $this->twilio_outgoing->account->calls->create. You are only passing the fromNumber and twoNumber to it. TwiML URL is missing here. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls Select Php language in the right side code panel to see Php example.

Comment: That is the third "XXX" right after "// The visitor's phone number" - It is code lifted straight from the Twilio example app.

Comment: If it helps any, the actual URL being used is

https://timothy.nextcallcrm.com/tools/outbound

Comment: Oh... yea... I see it now... Browsing timothy url did not give any output. So it is also possible that your dev URL which is hosted on your machine is not accessible outside your work network. Due to which Twilio is not able to retrieve the content and it Voice call fails.

Comment: That helps - I can see it from my computer but when you said that I browsed to it on my phone and found it isn't able to be seen from the outside!

Comment: So I think you can make it available thru some public URL and try again.

Comment: Yep - it works now. I had forgotten that the "timothy" URL is not seem outside our network was all.

Comment: Good to know that it resolved now. I am glad that I could help you resolving the issues. Thanks.